# How to Detect if Launcher Home Screen Supports Rotation

Tags: java, android, android-widget, screen-orientation

I need to check if the device launcher home screen support orientation, is that possible? if so please help me out.

for instance, Samsung Galaxy Note 2 does not support launcher orientation while Galaxy Mega does.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle yourself the screen rotations by modifying the Manifest file, just add `android:configChanges="orientation"` for the activities you want. It means that the system will not handle by itself the orientation changes anymore.

Then in order to implement the actions to do during the orientation changes, add the following code in your `Activity`:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            //TODO
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //TODO
        }
    }
```

For the devices, I think you can try filtering with the models for example: `android.os.Build.MODEL`.

Comment: Not Working because its a Widget ?

Comment: I don't know if there is a difference with the widgets, maybe just have a try to see if the event is called or not.